# Can an SQLite database or CoreData Store be bundled within iOS app and still be modified?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I know that when you build an iOS app and package files in its bundle ready for deploying it, those files in the bundle are not meant to be changed or tempered with as it would invalidate the app signing (correct me if am wrong).

Now, what if an app is shipped with an SQLite database or CoreData Store in the bundle which the app is expected to CRUD its records. Are changes possible in this case? Will the signing be invalid? Or will I need to copy the bundled store to a different location at run time to modify it?

Hope you can clarify
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Anything in the app bundle is read-only. Period.

Your only option is to copy the read-only file from the app bundle to a writable folder the first time your app runs and then only use the writable copy.

Comment: Glad to help. Please don't forget to accept answers that solve your questions.